# Как исправить отображение GitHub

Tags: emoji

По этой [ссылке](https://gist.github.com/roachhd/1f029bd4b50b8a524f3c) отображаются emoji. И там где флаги, у меня отображаются вот [так](http://prntscr.com/mna3i4), а должны нормальными иконками флагов! Не могу нигде найти, как исправить...???

Comment: Если обратить внимание, то флаги не отображаются. У меня лично - нет. Даже если посмотреть [это](https://gist.github.com/rxaviers/7360908), то там тоже нет флагов

Comment: хм, на других ПК отображаются отлично

Comment: Исправлять надо устройство, а не гитхаб. Если в железяке нет этих эмодзей, то она из не показывает.

Comment: У меня стандартно не отображаются флаги. Есть расширения (как минимум одно) для Хрома, добавляющее некоторые отсутствующие эмоджи. В любом случае, это не проблема гитхаба, это проблема браузера или системы.